# bootstrap 3, the button does not work on IE (java) (.jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, button

hello i'm using bootstrap 3 in a .jsp page and the button does not work
i'm using IE 10 (the browser that i need).

this is what is happen: the url change but the page does not

this is the button code:

```
<form action="main.jsp#dettaglio_ticket.jsp?ticket=<%=ticketL.get(x).id_ticket%>"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button></form>
```

this is the url starting page:

```
http://localhost:8090/HTM/main.jsp
```

and this is the targhet page:

```
http://localhost:8090/HTM/main.jsp#dettaglio_ticket.jsp?ticket=11111
```

so, is there a better way to do this?
also i tryed this two codes:

```
<button action="main.jsp#dettaglio_ticket.jsp?ticket=<%=ticketL.get(x).id_ticket%>" type="button" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right btn btn-primary btn-sm"></button>

<a class="btn btn-primary fa fa-arrow-circle-right" href='main.jsp#dettaglio_ticket.jsp?ticket=<%=ticketL.get(x).id_ticket%>'>Link</a>
```

and none of this one works, a parte the first one (the one the form syntax that works only on chrome, but i need IE 10)

thanks in advice

---

now i'm trying this five different syntax: 
1)

```
<form action="main.jsp#dettaglio_ticket.jsp?ticket=  <%=ticketL.get(x).id_ticket%>"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button></form>
```

2)

```
<button action="main.jsp#dettaglio_ticket.jsp?ticket=<%=ticketL.get(x).id_ticket%>" type="button" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right btn btn-primary btn-sm"></button>
```

3)

```
<a class="btn btn-primary fa fa-arrow-circle-right" href='main.jsp#dettaglio_ticket.jsp?ticket=<%=ticketL.get(x).id_ticket%>'>Link</a>
```

4)

```
<input TYPE="button" VALUE="Home Page" onclick="window.location.href='main.jsp#dettaglio_ticket.jsp?ticket=<%=ticketL.get(x).id_ticket%>'">
```

5)

```
<form><input TYPE="button" VALUE="Home Page" onclick="window.location.href='main.jsp#dettaglio_ticket.jsp?ticket=<%=ticketL.get(x).id_ticket%>'"> </form>
```

this is the starting page:
http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=200tips&s=8#.U7E71fl_sTQ

if i press the buttons numbers 1 and 2 nothing happens,

if i press the buttons number 3 and 4 and 5 the url changes but nothing else happens:

http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zyvqet&s=8#.U7E78Pl_sTQ

Comment: Is it a IE 10 specific problem or it does not work in other browser (Chrome, firefox) ?

Comment: @Pracede as i writed the first code button works on chrome, the others not

Comment: If you paste the URL in navigation bar works?

Comment: @MiguelAngel_LV yes it works prefectly if i paste it

Comment: Which url did you copy in the browser which works ? And show us the screen shot when it fails please

Comment: if i paste this "http://localhost:8090/HTM/main.jsp#dettaglio_ticket.jsp?ticket=11111" the page change correctly

Comment: For 1 and 2, could you give the servlet/mvc controller code which manage the request please ?

Comment: @Pracede

i resolved this by adding
    onClick="window.location.reload();"
on a link which change the url

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do when you hit the button.  Do you want to load the new page or navigate/focus on particular area of your page....

Usually # symbol used in url to navigate/focus on particular div..... it won't hit the server.... if you want to hit the server avoid using # symbol in url

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this by adding

```
onClick="window.location.reload();"
```

on a link which change the url